How to provide rsnapshot with a large initial dataset?
I have 400GB of data I have manually rsynced to my Linux backup server via SSH from a remote Linux server. I want to configure rsnapshot to keep incremental backups of that data from the remote server.
My initial 400GB of data is a month old and located on the backup server in /home/datastore. On the production server it is located in /mnt/datastore.
How can I configure rsnapshot to use that data for it's initial daily.0 snapshot and then continue to use that data for the daily/weekly snapshots? My goal is to transfer only the changes from the remote server thereby saving bandwidth?
Example: My backup line from rsnapshot.conf is the following:
backup  root@server:/mnt/datastore/targetdir/  targetdir/
I copy the initial data to daily.0/targetdir but I find that after running 'rsnapshot daily' it copies all of the data again but in the following path:
/home/rsnapshot/targetdir/mnt/datastore/targetdir
I have tries several ways to make this work but I am missing something.
Thanks!

I figured out what was happening. rsnapshot defaults to using rsync's --relative option which causes the full path to be created locally. I do not need relative paths in my rsnapshot configuration so I simply uncommented the following line in rsnapshot.conf:
#rsync_long_args    --delete --realative --numeric-ids --delete-excluded

and removed the --relative option. Now incrementals are working as expected. I hope this helps somebody else out there.
